# How to create triangle/jagged edges on a cylinder (e.g. for a lamp shade)

Tags: geometry

I'm looking for a good practice method of creating a triangle/jagged cylinder. My intention is to create a lamp shade with this zig-zag edges like the following. Basic stuff but I don't get it done.

[example image http://www.shapes.info/s/cc_images/teaserbox_2450143432.png?t=1421415920](http://www.shapes.info/s/cc_images/teaserbox_2450143432.png?t=1421415920)

So, I played around with circles and paths in combination with the (array) modifier(s) but didn't accomplish the desired result. I tried with the modifiers because I like the handy way to adjust the outcome.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward. **The advantage of this technique is it keeps the crease depth equal from top to bottom, just like a real world lamp shade.**

[image]

1. Create a cylinder. Choose No Caps, and set the subdivision to 64.
2. Scale the cylinder on the Z axis (<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) to get the correct height.
3. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into Edit mode, switch selection mode to Edges
4. Select one vertical edge, then in the Select menu choose **Select Similar>Length** to select all the vertical edges
5. Select **Checker Deselect** in the Select menu to deselect every other edge
6. Click <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to scale the selected edges in towards the centre of the cylinder
7. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into Object Mode and add the Simple Deform modifier
8. Adjust the Deform Factor to a negative value to get a narrow top and wide bottom for the lampshade.

[image]

Comment: Todd, you've invented a panel puzzle game recently. I think we can make another game. Here are the rules: You got the question and try to use as little as possible moves/clicks to solve the problem. The one who invents the shortest way to solve the problem wins. What do you think? :)

Comment: Haha, maybe a target mesh is provided, and then your result has to match the reference mesh vertex by vertex?

Comment: "The advantage of this technique is it keeps the crease depth equal from top to bottom, just like a real world lamp shade." - is that true? The fabric lampshades ones I found ("knife pleat" is a common description) that most closely matched OP's are actually noticeably deeper at the top (If I had to guess I'd say the length across the fabric is the same). Equal depth does look better than the other answer where they're deeper at the bottom, though.

Comment: Thank you Todd for your reply. The fact that these technique keeps the crease depth equal from top to bottom makes it perfect for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I'll show you the shortest path (I guess :)) of how to do it.

Add a *Circle* (Add-->Mesh-->Circle). Click ***Select-->Checker Deselect*** and set the values as pictured below.
[image]
[image]

Scale the selected vertices (<kbd>S</kbd>)
[image]

Then extrude them (<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>)
[image]

Scale the top and bottom edges of the object to achieve the desired shape. You may also add the *Solidify Modifier* to give the object some thickness.
[image]

Comment: The only issue with this technique is that he crease peaks are different sizes between the top and bottom edges. The real life lamp shade has even crease depth from top to bottom.

Comment: Yup, you're right, your technique is the best so far.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the **Add Mesh Extra Objects** Addon.

[image]

You can now add a star, and change the size of the top vertices.
[image]

Comment: The fastest way indeed, master cegaton. All kudos goes to you :).

Comment: @Gonzou I'm always on the lookout for the laziest way to get things done...

Comment: You're the man :).